# Calculating a score for each road in Openstreetmap produces unexpected result. What am I missing?

Tags: postgresql, gis, openstreetmap, postgresql-15

I have a Postgres database with a postgis extention installed and filles with open street map data.

With the following SQL statement :

```
SELECT                                                                
    l.osm_id,
    sum(
        st_area(st_intersection(ST_Buffer(l.way, 30), p.way))
        /
        st_area(ST_Buffer(l.way, 30))
    ) as green_fraction
FROM planet_osm_line AS l
INNER JOIN planet_osm_polygon AS p ON ST_Intersects(l.way, ST_Buffer(p.way,30))
WHERE p.natural in ('water') or p.landuse in ('forest') GROUP BY l.osm_id;
```

I calculate a "green" score.

My goal is to create a "green" score for each osm_id.

Which means; how much of a road is near a water, forrest or something similar.

For example a road that is enclosed by a park would have a score of 1.

A road that only runs by a river for a short period of time would have a score of for example 0.4

OR so is my expectation.

But by inspection the result of this calculation I get sometimes Values of

212.11701212511463 for a road with the OSM ID -647522

and 82 for a road with osm ID  -6497265

I do get values between 0 and 1 too but I don't understand why I do also get such huge values.

What am I missing ?

I was expecting values between 1 and 0.

Comment: Duplicate osm_ids that you are summing. Try without summing and grouping, to see the duplicate results for the IDs you mention.

Comment: the calculation takes around 4 days so I can only see if thats correct in 4 days :) But it seems to me your suggestion is plausible. Thank you.

Comment: if you do a quick test using for example "WHERE l.osm_id=-6497265 AND (p.natural........ OR .......)", you should get an instant response, provided that you have an index on osm_id, and a spatial index on the "way" column.

Comment: Another source of issue is that multiple polygons could overlap each others. You would have to `st_union` their geometries first.

Comment: On a side note, you can join using `st_dwithin()` instead of buffer+intersection. It will make use of the index and will be much faster.

Comment: could you please provide an example on how would I use st_dwithin() and st_union()?

Comment: This was mine approach: SELECT                                                                
    l.osm_id, st_area(ST_DWithin(l.way, p.way,30)) / st_area(ST_Buffer(l.way, 30)) as green_fraction
FROM planet_osm_line AS l
INNER JOIN planet_osm_polygon AS p ON ST_DWithin(l.way,p.way,30)
WHERE l.osm_id=-6497265 AND p.natural in ('water') or p.landuse in ('forest');
and I get No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom unique ID that you must populate, the query can also union eventually overlapping polygons:

```
SELECT                                                                
    l.uid,
    st_area(
        ST_UNION(
            st_intersection(ST_Buffer(l.way, 30), p.way))
    ) / st_area(ST_Buffer(l.way, 30)) as green_fraction
FROM planet_osm_line AS l
INNER JOIN planet_osm_polygon AS p 
    ON st_dwithin(l.way, p.way,30)
WHERE p.natural in ('water') or p.landuse in ('forest') 
GROUP BY l.uid;
```

Comment: just a follow up:this query worked beautifully. The previous query took around 4 days to complete. The suggested one by JGH took around 6 hours on my machine.